# Modify Windows Explorer in XP to show full length file names (in either hover over or "details" pane)?

Tags: windows, windows-xp, windows-explorer

Modify Windows Explorer in XP to show full file names (in either hover over or "details" pane)?  It truncates very long file names.

For Tiles view.

We won't be using List or Details view which I'm aware will show the full name (as does Icons view if you click on the file).

Comment: What do you mean to _show full file names_?

Comment: If a file name is very long Windows Explorer will truncate it in the hover over and details pane.

Comment: I don't think it's possible: The tiles always have the same size. If the file name is long and does not fit into the tile, the name is truncated; the full name is displayed in InfoTip when hover your mouse over the file tile.

Comment: Thanks for the response Alexey. In Tiles view, the InfoTip bubble also displays a truncated file name.

Comment: Maybe because the name doesn't fit on the screen? I have never seen this, InfoTip always displayed the full name if it was truncated on the tile.

Comment: See InfoTip truncation here. http://oi39.tinypic.com/33vojkp.jpg

File name is longest possible (max) for the directory. I've scrolled all the way to the right in the properties box.

Comment: I guess the file name is just _too long_. The majority of Windows apps can handles full paths up to 255 long, if only the file name is 255 characters long, then there's high probability you won't be able to open it easily. That may be the reason why Explorer truncates the name earlier.

Comment: I wish the InfoTip truncation could be controlled in the registry but it seems the number of characters to display in InfoTip is hardcoded. File name in the example above was under 255 because it was in a directory, however the full path (directory+filename) was 255 in total. Thanks anyway, Alexey. Excellent English by the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> [image]

Notice that the filename in the tooltip is displaying 127 characters. This is not a coincidence. Obviously what has happened is that the code responsible for displaying tooltips is using a signed BYTE which limits it to 127 characters. Had they used an unsigned byte, Explorer could have shown up to 255 characters. This is unfortunate for two reasons:

- Clearly, the code is already designed to support wrapping to more than one line, so no extra work would have to be done for that
- Windows (long) filenames are generally allowed to be up to 255 characters

This is likely just an oversight (read bug), but sadly, XP is no longer being supported, so there is not going to be a patch to fix it.

Of course, you could always use an alternate shell or file-manager. Not only do many of those have better support for things like this (you can file bug-reports and feature requests that actually get listened to), but they have a lot of other great features as well.

Comment: Ah - thank you for the accurate explanation!